# Murray Gell-Mann's independent discovery of group theory

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, history

In [this](https://fliptomato.wordpress.com/2007/03/19/medical-researcher-discovers-integration-gets-75-citations/) article I found an interesting remark on how group (representation) theory was introduced into the physical sciences :

> Murray Gell-Mann developed the “eight-fold way” to explain the spectrum of hadrons in the 1960s. It wasn’t until after he’d developed this formalism that he discussed his model with mathematicians, who then told him that he’d rediscovered group (representation) theory. This ushered ina new era in the history of particle physics where symmetry became our guiding light and group theory became a necessary tool for any particle theorist.

I didn't find much information on this, so my question is about what the "eight-fold way to explain the spectrum of hadrons" is and how it relates to group theory?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suitable to HSM SE.

Comment: Representations of groups were certainly not introduced in physics by Gell-Mann.  Weyl, Wigner, Bethe, Barmann, Casimir, Racah and a host of others used groups to classify particles, symmetry types, crystals etc in the 1920s and well-before Gell-Mann proposed the eightfold-way.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_physics_and_representation_theory

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_way_(physics)

Comment: If you are interested in this topic especially the representations of the commonly used groups U(1), SO(3), SU(2) and SU(3) (relevant for the Hadrons) and many anecdotes concerning Gell-Mann i recommend the lecture series on Group theory by Anthony Zee https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEovyfCFtBs&list=PLrLctLPAdPNsB9TGH3i1zUNjzlssmcfCI&index=6

Comment: The eightfold way applied SU(3) to particle physics, but this group had already been applied by Elliott to nuclear physics, long before. Bad history of science journalism rarely fails to confuse.

Comment: Try:  Elliott, J.P., 1958. Collective motion in the nuclear shell model. I. Classification schemes for states of mixed configurations. Proceedings of the Royal Society of London. Series A. Mathematical and Physical Sciences, 245(1240), pp.128-145.

Comment: ... and then there is the seniority scheme etc... the list is long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hermann Weyl and especially Élie Cartan are the mathematicians credited with the discovery of the so-called „classical groups”, theory and representations thereof. What Murray Gell-Mann did was simply to bring forth SU(3) and its Lie algebra in the center of a new physical theory, explicitely discussing the latter's finite-dimensional representations, which is basically what Weyl and especially Wigner had done from 1926 to 1930 for SO(3) and SU(2) in the context of symmetries (and particularly rotations) in the newly founded Quantum Mechanics. So MGM did not (re)discover anything in mathematics. He learnt group theory and applied it properly for his theory of the strong interactions.

Comment: Do you have a source for Gell-Mann learning group theory from G Racah ?

Comment: As pointed out by @CosmasZachos, the relevance of $SU(3)$ was already recognized by Elliott; he was using the $SU(3)\supset SO(3)$ subgroup chain to extract rotational bands.

Comment: @StephenG No, I couldn't find a source for that or for any other man teaching MGM about group theory, so I deleted that.

Comment: Thank for the response.  I confess I was kind of hoping you had a source as it's nice when people who teach the famous get credit.